# Firestore query with only a field inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

This is the thing I want to accomplish: I'm building a web shop. The web shop has a React Front-end. The front-end fetches [5 collections](https://github.com/turtle3808/ohana-s/blob/new-stripe-implementation/client/src/firebase/firebase.utils.js) from Firestore and displays all the items from the collection array on the shop page. A user selects an item on the shop page. [I send the item fields such as (price, name, quantity, id)](https://github.com/turtle3808/ohana-s/blob/new-stripe-implementation/client/src/components/stripe-button/stripe-button.component.jsx) to my [express server](https://github.com/turtle3808/ohana-s/blob/new-stripe-implementation/server.js) and the server makes a checkout session of the item fields. The user goes to a Stripe checkout form and is sent back to my front-end by Stripe when the payment is complete. I listen for that event on my server and when then want to update the quantity field of the item in Firestore.

But how do I query Firestore for this item? Is there a way to query Firestore with only this id field (or name field)? Some something like:

```
  db
      .collection('collections')
      .where('id', '===', 1)
```

Or do I need to save the document id (of the collection) as a field inside the item map and also send that to Stripe? Or is there a better way to do this? I can't find anything online about this.

[Here is a screenshot of Firestore.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT4fj.png)

Please forgive my beginner question. I'm still learning React, Firestore and Node.js.

Comment: Depending on what you need to pass around, and while I can't speak to firestore, once you have the items that you would like to sell (most probably mapped by ID to actual products and prices created in Stripe) you can also pass metadata as key: value pairs when creating a checkout session. https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata if you would like to pass through data. This metadata would then be available to you when the checkout session completes for example.

Comment: @v3nkman thank you for your reply. Yes using the metadata in the checkout session was exactly my idea. But how to update Firestore with the provided metadata is the problem now :)

Comment: Quick point: in Firestore you use "==", not "===".  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#opstr:-wherefilterop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure you are sticking to the Firestore terminology correctly.  There are `collections` and there are `documents`.

Collections you access via a path such as:

- `collRef = db.collection("products")`
- `collRef = db.collection("products").where("quanity_on_hand", ">", "0")`
- `collRef = db.collection("products").doc("12345").collection("purchase_history")`

The latter instance can also be accessed via `collRef = db.collection("products/12345/purchase_history")`.

In all the above cases you will get back a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference).

Documents you access such as:

- `docRef = db.collection("products").doc("12345")`
- `docRef = db.doc("products/12345")`

This returns you a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) for the document whose ID is "12345" in the collection "products".

So for your code example above, you want to use `docRef = db.doc("collections/1")` to get back the DocumentReference for the item you are after.  (Or, alternatively, you could use:  `docRef = db.collection("collections").doc("1")`

If you stick with the code that you have above, you'd get back a CollectionReference then you'd need to fetch the data with `.get()`, then extract the resulting documents (that will just be a single document), then work with that.  Oh...and you will need to put an "id" field into all of your documents because the document's ID value (the "name" of the document) is not part of the document by default so if you want to use `.where("id", "==", "1")`, then you need to add an "id" field to your document and populate it correctly.

If you go with `docRef = db.doc("collections/1")`, you are querying for the document directly and will get back a reference to just that one.  No need for extra fields, nor extracting a single document from a result set.